# Kernel Panic After apr upgrade

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi, raid

We are having issue install the ubuntu server 18.04.4 version in some workstation, or basically after the installation process. We are using the Server version to set a raid1(Software) Partition for the home folder.

We installed the system on UEFI  with one SSD for / and the RAID1 partition for the home. Just to mention all the disk are attached to a RAID Controller.

The installation fine, Then we had run the apt update and upgrade, and also the kernel has ben updated  but  after a reboot the system does not boot anymore saying  "It cannot open boot devices unknown-block(0,0)  error -6 .....kernel panic"

I boot from the older kernel try to force the update the kernel to the latest version with the following command:

- apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04

but even if the kernel seems to be installed it does not appear on the grub menu.

I really don have any idea to look for

There in any change to understand what happened during the updates? Is the media ubuntu-server-18.04.4 that gave us so many problems? Is the UEFI Partition the problem? i really don't understand

We tried also an installation with a standard desktop with a normal sata disk, with no raid, but the problems seems to be the same.

Any help is appreciated THANKS!
A.

Comment: It was just a test, because due to some incompatibility product with the kernel 5.x  and we used the server version, not only becuase of the kernel 4.x  but also because we needed  to setup a raid 1 partition during the installation. The installation was fine, the workstation didn't reboot after the first apt update/upgrade updating the kernel to 4.15.0.143.

Comment: Later question asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462734